# Limit the text input of editable QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to limit the possibility of text-input to the text of the combobox items.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    combo = QComboBox()
    combo.setEditable(True)
    combo.insertItems(0, ['Bob', 'Anne', 'Tim'])

    combo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the combobox above, I will not be able to type in e.g. 'Peter' or any other string that is unlike Bob, Anne or Tim.

EDIT:

I have already tried this code, but I failed and I don't know if I am on the right way:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox

class Validator(QValidator):

    names = ['Bob', 'Anne', 'Tim']

    def validate(self, _text, _pos):

        for name in self.names:
            if _text == name[0:_pos]:

                print(f"match")
                return QValidator.Acceptable
            return QValidator.Intermediate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    combo = QComboBox()
    combo.setEditable(True)
    combo.insertItems(0, ['Bob', 'Anne', 'Tim'])

    c_validator = Validator(combo.lineEdit())
    combo.setValidator(c_validator)

    combo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code runs into the error: 'TypeError: invalid result from Validator.validate()'

**Additional explanation:**

In the picture below you can see a combobox where you can enter a font style.
[image]

I have inputed here the three letters a, r and i. After pressing the return- or the tabulator-key the item 'Arial' is selected:

[image]

But in this combobox I can also input 'nonsens'. It does nothing! But to prevent an (inexperienced) user to input wrong stuff, I would like this behaviour.

Comment: You could install a custom QValidator on the combo's line edit.

Comment: What is the point of making the combo *editable*, if the user can't add their own items? Why not just initialise the combo with all the allowed items and make it read-only? Please edit your question and add a more realistic example that shows what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @ekhumoro: If you have a gui-interface  that is optimized for keyboard-input, than you have a better/faster workflow on searching and inputing data. This combobox should be a pattern-class for this needs.

Comment: @vezzon The QComboBox class already does that by default. When it has the keyboard focus, typing e.g. "A" will automatically select "Anne".

Comment: @ekhumoro: Yes, I know. But you can also type 'Peter' which is not in the itemlist!

Comment: @vezzon Not if the combo is read-only. In that case, typing "Peter" will do nothing. By definition, a read-only combo-box only allows the user to enter items that are already in the list. No validation is required.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Okay, and how can I set an editable combobox read-only. I have found no hint in the QComboBox Class?

Comment: @vezzon Well, `combo.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)` will do that, but I don't see the point. Why do you want the combo to appear editable, if the user can't actually edit anything? What ***exactly*** do you want the user to be able to enter? Please spell out, ***in simple terms***, what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @ekhumoro: E.g. I would like to select a customer in a form-widget. All other input-widget in this form are optimized to input data by keyboard. So I think when the combobox gets the focus by the tabulator , you can immideatly search and choose the item (customer) you want with the keyboard. But maybe there is better solution!?

Comment: @vezzon What do you mean by "search and choose"? Give some specific examples that can't be achieved using a standard read-only combo-box.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I have added a additional explanation.

Comment: @vezzon The statndard QComboBox already provides that exact behaviour. That is, it auto-completes (case-insensitively) on any valid combination of starting letters. So if the list of items is "Artist, Arrow, Arial, Armour", typing in "ari", automatically selects "Arial" (and there's no need to press return, either). Also note that Qt provides [QFontComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontcombobox.html) for the specific use-case given in your question.

Comment: @ekhumoro: It should not be specific for fonts (only in this example). But I can also enter here 'ariuz' which is not part of the itemlist. To avoid this, try to find out, how to limit the input-possibilities.

Comment: @vezzon This is just going round in circles. A standard, **read-only** combo-box already provides *the exact behaviour* that you currently describe in your question.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I don't think so. In a read-only combobox, as suggested, I cannot search so easy an item only with the keyboard (I don't want to use the mouse, because it is a waste of time on inputing a large amount of data). I know to hit three times on the 'A' key to get the third item beginning with an 'A'. In my cases I have sometimes 20 items in the itemslist and sometimes 200. So it would be a good and fast combination of finding and selecting an item.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Why do I get a TypeError in my edited example above?

Comment: @vezzon Well, I know so ;-) Typing "A" "R" "I" goes directly to the required item - try it! To do this, it simply searches the combo-box for any relevant items that start with those letters. This is exactly what a validator would have to do, making it effectively redundant. However, if you're determined to waste your time on this, the `validate` method must return a tuple of (state, text, pos) in PyQt (because the Qt implementation works by modifying the arguments, which Python does not support).

Comment: @ekhumoro: In my first try I cannot figure it out with a read-only item (Typing "A" "R" "I" goes directly to the required item). But I will test it more a little bit later. Thank you for your time you give to me!!!!